# How do you efficiently bucket/partition on a shared cluster that autoscales?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Edit: Using Spark with Databricks

As far as I understand, effective partitioning should be based on the number of executors available, ideally partitions % executors = 0

But if you work on a shared Spark cluster that autoscales according to activity, and in which people may be keeping some executors busy with their own work, is it possible to efficiently partition and bucket in this way?

Say I notice there are 8 exectutors active on the cluster, so I make 8 partitions or buckets to distribute the workload more easily. While that's happening, Alice and Jane log on and start running big queries, so the cluster upscales to say, 12 executors.

Now I'm no longer efficiently parititioned. Or what if the cluster doesn't upscale, but Alice and Jane take up some executors, now my partitions will be skewed, right?

Or... will Spark recognise that I have 8 partitions, and upscale as needed to match that if enough aren't immediately available?

Comment: When you say auto scale are you running it in databricks or any cloud services?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "cluster autoscaling". IME, when running Spark jobs on a cloud you can specify the amount of executors, allocated memory... to your job. When you launch your job, Spark request the ressources to the ressource manager (like YARN) and once the ressources are allocated you're not impacted by other jobs.

Comment: @AlexRajanSamuel Yep - databricks

Answer (score 1):

The rule `partitions % executors = 0` is applied to the efficient processing so you don't have less partitions than executors at some point of time. Really, the things are more complicated - partitions could be small, and then automatically coalesced when Adaptive Query Execution (AQE) kicks in, combining multiple small partitions into bigger logical partitions, etc. And it's one of the "optimizations" on Spark 3.x - set shuffle partitions to some big number, and allow AQE to optimize it, instead of ending with too big partitions.

Yes, on shared cluster, some of resources could be consumed by other users, but that's just will allocate less cores for your processing, but not skew your partitions. Skewed partitions are primarily related to the partitions of different sizes, but this also should be handled by AQE that is enabled on DBR 7.3+.

Overall: yes, on shared clusters some resources will be taken by other users, but otherwise it's better to rely on the improvements in the Spark 3.x in area of automatic optimization.  In previous versions there was a lot of manual tuning that isn't required in newer versions.

Comment: Alas, looks like I'm using Spark 2.4. Any tips here?

Comment: there is a bit of confusion about terminology - when we talk about skewed partitions, we're talking about partitions that have different sizes. In your case, it's more about resources allocation, so if other users will take some cores, yes - your execution won't be optimal anymore, but I don't think that this could be a critical issue. If cluster is expanded, then you'll have more cores to execute on, and execution could be faster